# Deleted Google form entries don't get deleted in the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form and the answers are stored in a Google Sheet. Sometimes I manually delete a singe entry from the form (because someone made a new entry with updated information). Unfortunately the Sheet will not update accordingly. It seems like only new form entries get pushed to the sheet instead of updating the whole sheet whenever a new answer is entered.

Initially I found the following solution:
A Google app script goes through the sheet, finds duplicate entries/rows, deletes the older/upper entry/row and keeps the newer/lower one. It works but this would't be necessary if I could get the sheet to updated the whole content.

So my question:
Is there a way to update the whole Google sheet when a new entry is made in the Google form or a manual edit is done? Or just make the sheet recognize manually deleted entries from the form?

Comment: Didn' try it before, but [`onFormSubmit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) trigger might help

Comment: thanks, for now my only solution is to delete the entry manually in the form, then open the sheet and there delete the corresponding row there manually as well.
Another way would be, after deleting the entry in the form, to unlink the currently linked sheet and link to a new one. Which is not practical thing.
Still hoping for a solution to this.